# What would be a proper way to model this deceiving simple shape?

Tags: modeling

I am fairly new in Blender coming from SketchUp.

After some hours 12 working with Blender i'vv tried different ways to precise model this "simple" shape into a single object. I seems like its better to not use the extrude manifold option. Some modeling guiding is very much appreciated :-)

[image: 3d]

[image: 2D]

[image: dimensions]

[image: make a cut on 2.2mm]

[image: make 2.2 mm height]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cube, stretch it on X, rotate it 45° on X, cut it in half and mirror with a *Mirror* modifier:

[image]

Select its end and in front view, use the *Shear* tool (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) and in the *Operator* box choose *Offset* > 1:

[image]

Cut an horizontal edge with the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> if it is supposed to be cut at its middle:

[image]

Extrude the bottom triangle on X:

[image]

To measure an edge, you can enable the *MeasureIt* addon. Select an edge then in the *N panel > View > MeasureIt Tool*, click on *Show* and clik on *Segment*. You can remove the display with the X buttons a bit below on the same panel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I can do it this way. Will try to be precise, the height of the little extruded triangle needs to be exactly 2.2mm perpendicular on the bottom edge.

Comment: there are some measure tools in Blender, you can activate the addon MeasureIt for example, not sure where these 2.2mm are supposed to be though, could you please add a picture in your original post?

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe try MeasureIt

Comment: Hi @moonboots I will add the measure it addon and give it a try, also added some dimensions.  Precise modeling is a bit difficult but can give it a try to move the 3D mouse and try to snap the knife tool to it if that is possible. thanks!

Comment: Blender is not made for industrial modelling but they are some tools that allow measurement like MeasureIt or Edit Mesh Tools, also Archimesh or Archipack addons

Comment: Not giving up easily :) getting close with your directions. Need to take a look on how to precisely cut with the knifetool

Comment: anyway once you've cut with the knife you can still move the edge loop with GG (slide)

Comment: Hi @Center :). If you need the triangle height to be precise, use [*Knife project*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html) instead of *Knife tool*.

Comment: Thanks you all, I'vv got the shape exactly precise combining the shear @moonboots suggested and fiddling aground moving vertices to the 3D cursor